# Error getting value from tables in relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I doing an app using 2 tables in relationship but i'm getting  "undefined method `num_letter' for nil:NilClass"

My tables

```
 index_letters:
   |id|  |num_letter|  


  letter_logs:
  |id|   |index_letter_id|
```

Here is my controller

```
class PolicyManagement::LetterLogController < ApplicationController
   def index_document
     @letter_logs = LetterLog.find(:all)
   end
end
```

My models:

```
class LetterLog < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :index_letter

end

class  IndexLetter < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :letter_logs
end
```

This is my view

```
<% @letter_logs.each do |letter_log| %>
   <%= letter_log.id %>
   <%= letter_log.index_letter.num_letter %>
<% end %>
```

I tried this

```
<% @letter_logs.each do |letter_log| %>
   <%= letter_log.id %>
   <%= letter_log.indexletter.num_letter %>
<% end %>
```

This is my log

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `num_letter' for nil:NilClass) on line #23 of app/views/policy_management/letter_log/_table.rhtml:
```

New logs:

```
  LetterLog Columns (2.3ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `letter_logs`
  IndexLetter Columns (1.2ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `index_letters`
  IndexLetter Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `index_letters` WHERE (`index_letters`.`id` = 0) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `index_letters` WHERE (`index_letters`.`id` = 0) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `index_letters` WHERE (`index_letters`.`id` = 0) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `index_letters` WHERE (`index_letters`.`id` = 0) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `index_letters` WHERE (`index_letters`.`id` = 0) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `index_letters` WHERE (`index_letters`.`id` = 0)
```

Please somebody can help me with this? I will really appreciate all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `letter_log.index_letter.try(:num_letter)`, the error you are getting is thrown if `letter_log.index_letter` is `nil`. This would happen if a `letter_log` has no associated `index_letter`.

`try` method returns `nil` if the calling object is `nil`.

Also something odd in your model

```
class LetterLog < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :index_letter
   has_many :letter_log # the class is associated to itself without any foreign key??
end
```

Comment: i removed has_many :letter_log and used ".try" but now is not showing values in my column,what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: that means there are no `index_letter` associated with `letter_log`. Run `rails console` and check if `index_letter` have any associated `letter_log`

Comment: Tihom , now is showing the id , of my other table but is not showing the value num_letter

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `IndexLetter` assigned to your `LetterLog` in your relationship.

The best practice in rails views is to use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) when you are uncertain if the object is present or not like so:

```
<% @letter_logs.each do |letter_log| %>
   <%= letter_log.id %>
   <%= letter_log.index_letter.try(:num_letter) %>
<% end %>
```

This will return `nil` without raising an error. Here is an excerpt from the docs:

```
a NoMethodError exception will not be raised and nil will be returned instead, if the receiving object is a nil object or NilClass
```

Comment: Well i tried your code but my column num_letter is blank now.
Is there any way to fix this problem?